# Cannot create an new interface when it belongs to project

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I try to create a new interface object. After clicking create button, it still remains `new.html.erb`, it should go to `project_interfaces_path`(main page). Also, the data has not saved yet.

I have tried many ways such as change URL, but it does not work and it reports NoMethodError in InterfacesController#create
undefined method `interfaces' for nil:NilClass

The `interface/new.html.erb`

```rb
<div class="card-body">
    <%= form_for @interface, url:project_interfaces_path,method: :post do |f| %>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :name %>
        <%= f.text_area :name,class: 'form-control'%>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :desp %>
        <%= f.text_field :desp,class:'form-control'%>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :request_url %>
        <%= f.text_field :request_url,class:'form-control'%>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :request_eg %>
        <%= f.text_field :request_eg,class:'form-control'%>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :response_eg %>
        <%= f.text_field :response_eg,class:'form-control'%>
      </div>
      <%=link_to  project_interfaces_path  do%>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">返回列表</button>
      <% end %>
      <%=f.submit "创建",class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
    <% end %>
```

The interface controller：

```rb
  def new
    @interface = Interface.new
  end

  def create
    @interface = @project.interfaces.new(interface_params)
    if @interface.save
      redirect_to project_interfaces_path
    else
      render :new 
    end
  end

private
  def interface_params
    params.require(:interface).permit(:id, :name, :desp,:request_url,:request_eg,:response_eg)
  end
```

The interface belongs to project:

```rb
class Interface < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :method_type
  has_many :get_fields, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :put_fields, dependent: :destroy
  belongs_to :project
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're working with nested resources, it means you can't create an interface without project_id, since Interface `belongs_to :project`. How it should be:

```
def new
  @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
  @interface = @project.interfaces.new
end

def create
  @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
  @interface = @project.interfaces.build(interface_params)
  if @interface.save
    redirect_to project_interfaces_path(@project)
  else
    render :new 
  end
end

private
def interface_params
  params.require(:interface).permit(:id, :name, :desp,:request_url,:request_eg,:response_eg)
end
```

And remove url and method options from form, it works automagically

```
<%= form_for @interface do |f| %>
```

Comment: Your answer is correct. It works for my project. Thank you

Comment: @HaoWen happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, you are redirecting to `new` instead of `project_interfaces_path`:

```rb
def create
  @interface = Interface.new(interface_params)
  if @interface.save
    #redirect_to new_project_interface_path(project) <- wrong path
    redirect_to project_interfaces_path # Good path
  else
    render :new 
  end
end
```

Also, add a space  between `url:` and `project_interfaces_path` in  `<%= form_for @interface, url:project_interfaces_path,method: :post do |f| %>`.

UPDATE: It seems you are trying to save an `Interface` without associate a `Project` to it.

You need to retrieve a project and build the interface with it:

```rb
  def new
    project = Project.find(params[:id]) # Assuming you are sending it
    @interface = project.interfaces.build
  end

  def create
    project = Project.find(params[:id]) # Assuming you are sending it                                        
    @interface = project.interfaces.build(interface_params)
    if @interface.save
      redirect_to project_interfaces_path
    else
      render :new 
    end
  end
```

Taking a look on your routes would help.

Comment: sorry,mate. It is not that problem

Comment: the data cannot be saved into database.

Comment: Can you provide any output to the browser or log, please?

Comment: After clicking create button, it shows this url 127.0.0.1:3000/projects/7/. Moreover, since the interface belongs to the project, They told me that the project id has not put into.

Comment: Please, add the output of the command `rails routes -g project` to your original question.

Comment: when typing rails routes -g project. it shows many project_interfaces GET    /projects/:project_id/interfaces(.:format)          interfaces#index
                       POST   /projects/:project_id/interfaces(.:format)          interfaces#create

Comment: new_project_interface GET    /projects/:project_id/interfaces/new(.:format)      interfaces#new
edit_project_interface GET    /projects/:project_id/interfaces/:id/edit(.:format) interfaces#edit
     project_interface GET    /projects/:project_id/interfaces/:id(.:format)      interfaces#show
                       PATCH  /projects/:project_id/interfaces/:id(.:format)      interfaces#update
                       PUT    /projects/:project_id/interfaces/:id(.:format)      interfaces#update
                       DELETE /projects/:project_id/interfaces/:id(.:format)      interfaces#destroy